# Need help in SQL Query and output in Percentage format (VB 6 Flex Grid)

Tags: sql, vb6, sybase

Example:

Col A  68 Col B 67

My requirement is Col A /(divided by) Col B and the result format should be 99 % in the VB Flex Grid.

the query I have used earlier was

"sum(case when user_id is not NULL and datediff (ss, callstartdt, QueueEndDt) <= 20 then 1 else 0 end)  / count(seqnum),"

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to my informations, 68/67 is is about 1.0149253731343284, not 0.99.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply multiply the value by 100 and truncate or round the decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to multiply your result by 100, use the Str function to convert it to a string and then tack on a percent sign.

```
Str(
    Sum(    Case 
            When user_id Is Not NULL 
                And DateDiff (ss, callstartdt, QueueEndDt) <= 20 Then 1 
            Else 0 
            End)  /  Count(seqnum) * 100, 10 ) + '%'
```

However, it should also be noted that the Flexgrid might allow you to simply format the returned decimal value as a percent which would do the multiplication and inclusion of the percent sign for you. I'm not familiar with the Flexgrid so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: I have resolved that issue... thanks for all...flexDet.TextMatrix(i, 6) = Format(rst.Fields(3) / rst.Fields(1), "00.00%")